# Use mutiple datepicker to make calculation

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I have a table that contain 18 bootstrap datepicker, each of them are usefull for my purpose. The month is set in a format like: `12 febreo 2018`, each of them has a `linkField` which I use to make the calculation of difference of day between the `linkField` date gotten after picking a date and another date that is shown up on page load. I use moment js to make the difference.

The calculation is perfect but my issue is the fact that I use 18 selectors the page takes 9 seconds to load, how can I handle the datepickers, or what is the best way to use them  to make the page load faster?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Day 1 </td>
    <td>
      <div class="input-group date form_date"  data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" >
        <input type="text"  class="form-control"  readonly >
      </div>
      <input  id="mirror_f1"  type="hidden"> 
      <input type="text" value="07 February 1989">
      <input  id="mirror_f2" value="1989-02-07"  type="hidden"> 
      <span><i>Day difference :</span>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <!--//17 more rows
  .
  .
  .
 -->
</table>
<script>
  $('.form_date').datetimepicker({
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn:  1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 2,
    minView: 2,
    forceParse: 0,
    linkField: "mirror_f1",
  });
  //17 more selectors
</script>
```

Comment: Are you able to use framework like Angular ?

Comment: I don't know it yet, i have to learn it. While i do  is there another way to reach my goal with jquery ?

Comment: Any others ideas ?